# how to put the iOS application in background for a few seconds in order to solve camera shutter closed issue?

Tags: ios, camera

i am working on an iPad application that takes pictures with a custom overlay camera. For the first time the shutter is open but after that it is closed . When it is closed , i tried pressing the sleep iPad button for a few seconds and then the shutter opened again. I tried also to press the home button that hided the application and when i opened the application again the shutter opened. These two actions are equal with putting the application in background the two methods application will resign and application didenterbackground methods are called. I was wondering if i could put the application in background for a few seconds programmatically without violating app store rules. Could i press the sleep iPad button for a few seconds programmatically ? I have tried the [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=yes; and directly afterwards [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=no; in the overlayviewcontroller´s viewdidload method , but it did not work. Is this method supposed to put the application in background? Is it accepted by apple store rules. I was wondering if you could give me some help with this issue?

Thank you in advance, Best regards

Answer (score 3):

> Is this method supposed to put the application in background?

No, it's for something else, but why don't you read its documentation?

> Is it accepted by apple store rules?

(You mean AppStore, right? At Apple Store, we can buy hardware...)

No, what you described is completely against AppStore's user interface guidelines. Your app is likely to be rejected if you somehow manage to achieve this behavior.

> I was wondering if i could put the application in background for a few seconds programmatically without violating app store rules.

Unfortunately, no.

By the way, your best chance for at least doing this is calling `- [SBUIController animateApplicationSuspend:]`, but again it's hooking directly into SpringBoard and thus it is explicitly prohibited.

What you can do is file a bug report if you really believe this is a bug in iOS.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes. Thank you very much for your valuable information. I was wondering if you could advice me into other ways to solve the closed camera shutter issue? Thank you in advance, Best regards

Comment: @ThomasKertsalιs If this is a bug, there's no much you could do apart from sending Apple a bug report. If this is not, then if you start a completely new project with only a basic camera interface inside, it should work. Or maybe this error is present only on the simulator - try on a real device.